# MSSQL Race Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, race-condition

Would this SQL Stored Procedure encounter race condition issues?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[basket_add]
    @item_no BIGINT,
    @child_item_no BIGINT,
    @order_no NVARCHAR(50),
    @qty SMALLINT,
    @curr_code NVARCHAR(3),
    @store_id TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @price_gbp DECIMAL(18,2), @price_curr DECIMAL(18,2);
        DECLARE @rtn_tbl_basket TABLE (id bigint);
        IF @qty > 0 
        BEGIN
            --Call product price function to get latest product price
            SELECT  @price_gbp  = gbp_price 
                   ,@price_curr = curr_price
            FROM product_price(@item_no,@child_item_no,@curr_code,@store_id) WHERE curr_code = @curr_code;

            --Ensure price exists for specified product
            DECLARE @errormsg NVARCHAR(100) = 'Errors found, product/price does not exist: ' + CAST(@item_no AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '-' + CAST(@child_item_no AS NVARCHAR(10));
            IF ISNULL(@price_gbp,0) = 0 RAISERROR (@errormsg, 16, 2) WITH SETERROR; 

            INSERT INTO basket(order_no, item_no,child_item_no, qty, price, curr_price, curr_code)
            OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @rtn_tbl_basket(id)
            VALUES (@order_no,@item_no,@child_item_no,@qty,@price_gbp, @price_curr, @curr_code)

            --return success
            SELECT id AS rtn_basket_id ,1 AS success FROM @rtn_tbl_basket 
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
    SELECT 
            --return failure
            (SELECT id FROM @rtn_tbl_basket) as rtn_basket_id, 
            0 AS success, 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; 
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: can you be more specific with your question? explain what your code is doing and where you think the issue is, otherwise you're expecting users to digest and understand your SQL, before actually answering your question.

Comment: I know race issues normally occur with upserts, but was wondering is there is a chance in the above SQL that the insert into basket may occur before the price is returned from the function? Or other processes calling this code would could issues?

Comment: Are you referring to situations where there is more than one process running this procedure perhaps?

Comment: SQL statements are run sequentially so if you ask for the latest price before the insert then there's no chance of a race condition.

Comment: Thanks Tanner, Elliveny yes this code will be called by multiple processes

Comment: Tanner is indeed correct. But I'm wondering what you have observed which caused you to raise this question?

Comment: I haven't observed anything yet, just being cautious :)